# Delete Specific Extension files from the C: drive excepts from two folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm looking for a batch script commands that deletes all the files of specific extension (example .exe, .log) from my C: drive except from the two folders (folder_A and folder_B). Any idea how can I achieve this.

I'm using the below code but it's deleting the files from the manual folder also

```
If exist "D:\" (
for /D %%D in (*.*) do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="manual" del *.txt /s "%%~D"
)
pause
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your first sentence defines your question as [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we do not look for batch scripts or commands for you. On StackOverflow, you're expected to provide a [mcve] of your written code for a specific task, with along side it, sufficient information that we can replicate the issue you've identified. Given that information, the community will help to address that specific issue. Please therefore, use the search facility, and formulate some code before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59105126/edit) to bring it on topic. Thank you.

Comment: You need to open a Command Prompt window and enter `del /?` to read the usage information for the `del` command. It is also noteworthy that you are currently parsing directories which contain a period!

Comment: Perhaps, `@For /D %%D in (D:\*)Do @If /I Not "%%~nxD"=="manual" Del /Q /S "%%D\*.txt"` is closer to what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
If exist "D:\" ( 
  for /D %%D in (*.*) do ( 
    if /I not "%%~nD"=="manual" del /q /s "%%~D\*.txt" 
  ) 
)
pause
```

Note that you didn't also close the `if exist` code block.